# Problems with guess a number game

Tags: php

Hey, I am so close to fininshing my guess a number game, very simple in PHP, but for some reason I am stuck. I am storing the variable in a hidden form, but obviously each time the page is sent it resets the number so you can never get the right one.

Any ideas? My code is below.

```
<?php
// generate a random number for user to guess
$number = rand(1,100);

if($_POST["guess"]){

    // grab the user input guess
    $guess  = $_POST['guess'];
    $numbe  = $_POST['number'];
    if ($guess < $number){ 
        echo "Guess Higher";
    }elseif($guess > $number){       
        echo "Guess Lower";
    }elseif($guess == $number){      
        echo "You got it!";
    }
    echo "<br />Random Number:".$number."<br />";
    echo $guess;
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Guess A Number</title>
</head>

<body>
<form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post" name="guess-a-number">
    <label for="guess">Guess A Number:</label><br/ >
    <input type="text" name="guess" />
    <input name="number" type="hidden" value="<?= $number ?>" />
    <input name="submit" type="submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, typo.
As an extra exercise you should convert your code to use method="GET" but still hide the answer in the URL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

```
// generate a random number for user to guess
$number = rand(1,100);
```

To:

```
if(isset($_POST['number'])) {
   $number = $_POST['number'];
} else {
   $number = rand(1,100);
}
```

Comment: Thank you that got it to work, and it is not refreshing each time thanks to the conditional.

Ryan

Comment: Also, the typo pointed out by Ates should be removed altogether with this solution (no need to reasign number, we already have it set).

Answer (score 3):

Is it because of this typo?

```
$numbe  = $_POST['number'];
//numbe -> number
```

Answer (score 2):

I realise you're probably just starting out but the earlier you learn this stuff, the better:

```
echo "<br />Random Number:".$number."<br />";
```

This is leaving you open to an XSS attack - I could send `$_POST['number']` as `<script> doSomethingBad(); </script>`

You should either cast it to an integer (`$number = (int)$_POST['number']`) or escape your output (`echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['number']);`)

The same goes for `$guess` of course.

Interestingly, if you're using mod_rewrite, `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` could also be manipulated to do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Do something like:

```
$number  = $_POST['number'];
if ($number == null) {
    $number = rand(1,100);
}
```