# PHP Rand() resetting in maths game

Tags: php, math, random

I'm using PHP's `Rand()` function to generate two random numbers that I can compare against the user's, and echo out a success message if the user's answer equals (1st random number + 2nd random number.) However, I'm running into problems.

I suspected that the form was re-generating the numbers every time the form POSTED and the input was collected, so I tried using sessions instead to keep those numbers persistent. It's a mess to say the least.

I found this existing post: [Problems with guess a number game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546173/problems-with-guess-a-number-game) , but the solution didn't remedy my problem.

```
    <?php
        if(empty($_POST)) 
        {
            $_SESSION['$number1'] = Rand(0, 100);
            $_SESSION['$number2'] = Rand(0, 100);
        }

        if($_POST["submit"])
        {
            $input = $_POST['input'];

            if($input == ($_SESSION['$number1'] + $_SESSION['$number2']))
            {
                echo "Correct! ";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "Incorrect! ";
            }
        }

        echo "<hr><br> What is... <b>" . $_SESSION['$number1'] . " + " . $_SESSION['$number2'] . "</b>";
    ?>

    <form action="" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="input">
        <input type="submit" name="submit">
    </form>

<?php
    echo "<b>DEBUG ANSWER: </b> " . ($_SESSION['$number1'] + $_SESSION['$number2']);
?>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You are resetting your numbers now everytime the form is not posting something. A more logical approach might be to just check if you already have a number in session and reset only if not.
A seperate "new game" request could enforce resetting even if session contains a number.

Comment: And a minor question besides this ... why are you generating two random numbers and not just one? It would be exactly the same wit only one here.

Comment: it seems it works. Just replace your  if($_POST["submit"]) with a else if

Comment: @ToBe That works? It's always generated the same number twice when I've tried that.

Comment: If random generates the same number twice, there is something seriouilsy wrong with your code. You can safely assume that random generates something different everytime. If in doubt, use `mt_rand()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed a few things, personally, I wouldn't use the session, rather user hidden inputs. (if you're worried about security.. you shouldn't be.. numbers game, not banking site)

```
<?php
//Create a function to generate the random numbers (So we can re-use it)
function generateNumbers()
{
    $one = Rand(0, 100);
    $two = Rand(0, 100);
    //Now return the random numbers
    return array('number1' => $one, 'number2' => $two);
}

//Check if the submit button has been clicked
if($_POST["submit"])
{
    $input = $_POST['input'];

    if($input == $_POST['number1'] + $_POST['number2'])
    {
        echo "Correct! ";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Incorrect! ";
    }
}

//Now we create the numbers
$numbers = generateNumbers();

echo "<hr><br> What is... <b>" . $numbers['number1'] . " + " . $numbers['number2'] . "</b>";
?>

    <form action="" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="input">
        <input type="submit" name="submit">
        <!-- Personally I would rather use hidden inputs, than use the session -->
        <input type="hidden" name="number1" value="<?php echo $numbers['number1'] ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="number2" value="<?php echo $numbers['number2'] ?>" />
    </form>

<?php
echo "<b>DEBUG ANSWER: </b> " . ($numbers['number1'] + $numbers['number2']);
?>
```

Comment: Good answer (and what I'd do).  Only alteration I'd suggest is to change if($_POST["submit"]) into if(isset($_POST["submit"])).  This will safely check for the existence of the key.  Alternatively you could use if(count($_POST)>0) to check to see if anything has been posted :)

Comment: Keep in mind that the numbers can now be seen in your HTML and anyone can cheat without effort now. A session would make it safe. But it depends on the tech skills of your target audience ;)